# Crash on changing action bar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm adding

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

to my main activity onCreate. As soon as the app's execution starts, it stops responding. What am I doing wrong?

My AndroiManifest

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

My styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

Using minSdkVersion 21.

Comment: check this tutorial  http://tech-papers.org/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) (as that what corresponds with the AppCompat theme), you should **always** use [getSupportActionBar()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()) instead of `getActionBar()` - as of revision 21, `getActionBar()` will always return `null` for `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

**`getSupportActionBar()`** -- `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`
return android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

**`getActionBar()`** -- `android.app.Activity`
return android.app.ActionBar

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new  ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(colorCode));
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

For more details you can visit [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)